# Posting text and image to my Facebook 'wall' from Codenameone app

Tags: facebook, codenameone

What I am trying to do from my Codenameone app, in Eclipse, is to send a piece of Text and an Image to my Facebook wall. Simple (or is it). Can anyone explain to me how to achieve this in Java (in a CN1 app) please?

I am not wanting the user to login to facebook in my app. Instead, to achieve this in the same way that many mainstream apps do this (eg. BBC News app) where they use the Facebook app, that is already installed on the device, in the list of destinations to Share to, which resolves the FaceBook connection issue. If the user doesn't have FB app installed then I will not make this available to them.

I have read articles online but they are a number of years old (post out of date) or make use of tokens (for which I have little knowledge how to implement).

Assuming the above is possible then any information on formatting the destination post would be a real plus.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you just need sharing functionality that allows sharing on any platform  or Facebook share only?

Comment: Simply to share with Facebook only. I was referring to 'Sharing' as an example of how other apps achieve this, but i will just push the message onto their Facebook wall.

Comment: You are not allowed to prefill the message

Comment: @WizKid is right, you are only allowed to pre-fill facebook sharing with a link.

Comment: Correct. I would add that you should probably use the share button which allows you to share natively to anything (facebook, whatsapp etc.) based on the apps installed on the device.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'll research how to use the share functionality and give the user the option to push the data into shared apps. Similar to post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568553/codename-one-how-to-share-a-link-to-your-app/36571381

Answer (score 0):

Answered by @WizKid, @Diamond, @Shai Almog. 
I have put a ShareButton component on my screen allowing the user share with FB, Twitter etc.

```
ShareButton sb = new ShareButton();
        sb.setUIID("Label");
        sb.getAllStyles().setAlignment(Component.TOP);
        String imageFile = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + getMyFileName();
        sb.setImageToShare(imageFile, "image/png");
        sb.setTextToShare("My Text to share");
```

This works nicely, although its doesn't put the text from my setTextToShare() into FB but does Twitter and Email. Strange. Photo goes up and it does allow me to type my own text in.